# Product Pricing issue with custom collection and custom tier price magento2

Tags: magento2, tierprice, configurable-price

1. Added 'from date' and 'to date' to Advance pricing model, ti[image: User can enter different different price for different price range, there may be cases like current date is lies between multiple rows]
2. I am writing custom rest api's on with some custom conditions. like

   ```
   $_productCollectionFactory = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       //->setStoreId($storeId)
       ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $allCategoryIds])
       ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', ['eq' => $productType])
       ->addAttributeToFilter('approval', ['in' => $this->productHelper->getAllowedApprovalStatus()])
       ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
       ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
       ->addFinalPrice()
       //->addMinimalPrice()
       ->distinct(true);
   ```
3. List may have simple and configurable products.
4. **How can i calculate price, special price and per off with those tier price and product main price.**
5. **Also in case of configurable there is no price or tier price with main product so in this case minimum main price from a active in_stock child product and minimum tier price from active and in_stock child product whose tier price from date <= current_date and to_date >= current_date**
6. Below is my previous code/conditions which i added to collection is as

   ```
   //price join
   $_productCollectionFactory->getSelect()->joinLeft(
     array('ad' => 'catalog_product_entity_decimal'), 
     "e.entity_id = ad.entity_id AND ad.attribute_id = '77' AND ad.store_id='".$storeId."'",
     [
      'product_price' => "ad.value"
     ]
   );
   $_productCollectionFactory->getSelect()->joinLeft(
     array('tier_price' => 'catalog_product_entity_tier_price'), 
     "e.entity_id = tier_price.entity_id AND from_date <= '".$todayStartOfDayDate."' AND to_date >= '".$todayEndOfDayDate."'",
     [
      'custom_special_price' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('IF(MIN(tier_price.value) > 0, MIN(tier_price.value), "")'),
      'final_pricea' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('IF(MIN(tier_price.value) <  ad.value, MIN(tier_price.value), ad.value)'),
      'per_off' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('IF(MIN(tier_price.value) <  ad.value, ((ad.value - MIN(tier_price.value)) * 100 )/ ad.value, 0)')
     ]
   );
   ```

   7. Above code is creating issue with configurable products, its not calculating configurable child product min tier price for current date if any.
   8. I want a solution which will work with above condition and also price sort and price layered navigation.
   9. Any solution, idea or a common place where i can create or write custom logic will be helpful.